# Plotting multiple series from file using Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, series

I've got a data file of the form:

```
Series_1 "12-Dec-2011 12:00" 32
Series_1 "12-Dec-2011 12:01" 29
Series_1 "12-Dec-2011 12:02" 27
Series_1 "12-Dec-2011 12:04" 23

Series_2 "12-Dec-2011 12:01" 45
Series_2 "12-Dec-2011 12:02" 43
Series_2 "12-Dec-2011 12:04" 38
```

Which I'd like to plot as a number of series on the same plot using gnuplot, but I'm new to gnuplot and I cannot figure out how the `using` clause should be structured here.

I wanted to plot column 2, date/time as the X axis with column 3 as the Y axis, with subsequent sections being overlaid. Is this possible? Surely the X axis doesn't always have to be in the first column?

I tried:

```
plot "datafile.dat" using 2:3 title 'Hits'
```

But got the error:

```
x range is invalid
```

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818797/gnuplot-plotting-several-datasets-with-titles-from-one-file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to plot date/time series on the x axis you need to `set xdata time`. Next you need to tell gnuplot in what format the date/time data is. In your case

```
set timefmt "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M"
```

should do the trick. Some examples, as well as the `%X`-synonyms are shown [here](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/datetime-e.html).

You might want to set the format the x axis should be displayed. In your case maybe

```
set format x "%H:%M"
```

would make sense.

I was not able to plot your data with the quotation marks around the date/time. With this data file (*Data.csv*):

```
Series_1 12-Dec-2011 12:00 32
Series_1 12-Dec-2011 12:01 29
Series_1 12-Dec-2011 12:02 27
Series_1 12-Dec-2011 12:03 23

Series_2 12-Dec-2011 12:01 45
Series_2 12-Dec-2011 12:02 43
Series_2 12-Dec-2011 12:04 38
```

and this script:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M"
set format x "%H:%M"

plot "Data.csv" u 2:4 w l
```

you should get this

[image]

result.

Comment: Thanks. I included the quotes as, in the help section it states: ...white space divides each record into columns. However, whitespace inside a pair of double quotes is ignored when counting columns, so the following datafile line has three columns:
       1.0 "second column" 3.0

Answer (score 12):

Expanding @Woltan's answer: if you want each section in a different colour/style, use the `index` (but then you have to separate sections by *two* emtpy lines):

```
plot 'i' index 0 using 2:4 with lines, '' index 1 using 2:4 with lines
```

Comment: +1 choroba your answer was the resolution of a 4 hour research how to separate the sections. I haven't tried two newlines.

Comment: To be clear, two empty lines means _three_ newlines.