# Automatically Title Arbitrary Number of Blocks

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot individual blocks from a file separately. I've found that this works:

```
$ cat test
A
0 0
1 1


B
0 0
1 2


C
0 0
1 3
```

Then

```
gnuplot> plot for [i=0:2] 'test' index i with lines title columnhead
```

gives me three separate lines labeled A,B,C. Perfect.

But I don't know the number of blocks in the file, so I have problems. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14825558/3371623) suggests using `stats` to get the number of blocks in a file, but `stats` fails with `bad data on line 6` (the title, "B", of the second block).

I have control over the input file, so I can format that differently if needed.

How can I plot an arbitrary number of blocks (individually) with automatic titling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With gnuplot version 5.0 you can use `set key autotitle columnheader` before you call `stats`:

```
set key autotitle columnheader
stats 'test'

set style data lines
plot for [i=0:STATS_blocks-1] 'test' index i
```

That doesn't work with 4.6 and earlier versions. Here, you can use an external tool like `grep` to filter the data when passed to `stats`. To remove all lines which don't start with a digit or aren't empty one can use

```
stats '< grep -v "^[^0-9]" test'
```

or

```
stats '< grep ''\(^[0-9]\)\|\(^$\)'' test'
```

to determine the number of data sets, which is stored in the variable `STATS_blocks`.

Comment: `set key autotitle columnheader` doesn't issue any errors when I try this in gnuplot 4.6. Are you saying that the behavior has changed in 5.0?

Comment: When I use `set key autotitle columnheader; stats 'test'` I get the error `Bad data on line 6`, which is where the second title is. With 5.0 I don't get such an error, and `stats` returns me the number of data blocks. Alternatively you can use `grep` to filter out all lines which don't start with a digit or aren't empty, like `stats '< grep -v ''^[^0-9]'' test.dat'` (or `stats '< grep ''\(^[0-9]\)\|\(^$\)'' test.dat'`). That works also with earlier versions.

Comment: `grep` did the trick, do you want to post that as a separate pre 5.0 answer?