# Gnuplot: Plotting several datasets with titles from the pipe

Tags: dataset, pipe, gnuplot

As a follow up of: [Gnuplot: Plotting several datasets with titles from one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818797/gnuplot-plotting-several-datasets-with-titles-from-one-file), I have a `test.dat` file:

```
"p = 0.1"
1 1
3 3
4 1


"p = 0.2"
1 3
2 2
5 2
```

and I can plot it with no issues from within gnuplot using:

```
> plot for [IDX=0:1] 'test.dat' i IDX u 1:2 w lines title columnheader(1)
```

however I cannot pipe the data.

Here is the single line example:

```
$ cat test.dat | gnuplot --persist -e "plot for [IDX=0:1] '-' i IDX u 1:2 w lines title columnheader(1)"
line 10: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

I get the warning message and only the first set is plotted. I tried to add an `e` at the end of the data file, but no luck... This should be trivial, am I making a silly mistake?

---

I've messing around a bit more. So these works:

```
gnuplot --persist -e "plot for [IDX=0:1] 'test.dat' i IDX u 1:2 w lines title columnheader(1)"
gnuplot --persist -e "plot for [IDX=0:1] '< cat test.dat' i IDX u 1:2 w lines title columnheader(1)"
```

These don't:

```
cat test.dat | gnuplot --persist -e "plot for [IDX=0:1] '-' i IDX u 1:2 w lines title columnheader(1)"
cat test.dat | gnuplot --persist -e "plot for [IDX=0:1] '< cat' i IDX u 1:2 w lines title columnheader(1)"
```

It looks like a bug to me. I tried few Gnuplot versions (4.6.6, 5.0.0, 5.0.3) but they all present the same behaviour.

Comment: Would it be suitable to use the gnuplot `<` filename keyword to getdata from pipe? And does it work that way?

Comment: @bibi not really, since I'm streaming the data from another process, but yes `plot '< cat test.dat'` works... what a weird issue! I should be able to solve pretty easily going through the disk, but the pipe *should* work as well.

Comment: I still can't figure out why not run your command from within gnuplot

Comment: @bibi that's because I wanted to ship a single Python script. Doing as you suggests forces me to ship a Python and a Gnuplot script and the user needs to launch the latter, which may be confusing as it breaks my previous standard.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've finally got it browsing the documentation. When piping, each index selection requires to repeat the whole data:

```
plot '-' index 0, '-' index 1
2
4
6


10
12
14
e
2
4
6


10
12
14
e
```

or, as a much simpler alternative, one can just do:

```
plot '-', '-'
2
4
6
e
10
12
14
e
```